# Call function1 || function2 syntax error

Tags: c++

I would like to use `||` between two function calls so I can get the result of the `or` of those calls.  Here is what I tried:

```
bool UI() || bool UL()
```

However, I am getting an error saying `expected initializer before token`.

Comment: Are you trying to compute the OR of two functions?

Comment: remove the word `bool`? your question isn't very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a function, you don't put the function's return type in the call. The following should work:

```
bool result = UI() || UL();
```

Comment: @JonAbraham be aware that `UL()` may not always be called with that syntax.  If `UI()` returns `true` then the or is true, so it will skip executing `UL()`.  If it's important to call `UL()` every time you will want to store both results and do an or on those after

Comment: I didn't think C++ used lazy evaluation?